# String buffer function setCharAt() throws error

Tags: java, string

I tried to run this code and remove all uppercase characters and print the changed string again. But all it does is throwing me a "cannot find symbol - method delete(int,int)" error in the String function. I'm pretty sure the loop variable is visible too.

```
    String s = "Some Random Sentence Here";
    int l = s.length()
    for(int i = 0;i<l;i++)
    {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isUpperCase(ch) == true)
        {
           s.delete(i,(i+2));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

**Edit**: Thanks Mentallurg, forgot the i less than l part

Comment: `s` is a `String` which doesn't have a method `delete()`.

Comment: This code does not use `setCharAt`, so how could it throw an error?

Comment: are you using String or StringBuffer? You mentioned StringBuffer in comments but String in demo code.

Comment: gotcha thanks guys. I tried using the setCharAt() but it threw the same error. And yeah im using string not sting buffer sorry bout that

Comment: its still going to fail for index out of bound as you are deleting the characters but your loop consider the length as same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments there is no deletefunction for a string. String behaves a bit like a primitive type in Java but in the end not really.

Anyways you can solve the problem easy with streams as shown here:

```
String s1 = "Some Random Sentence Here";
s1=Arrays.stream(s1.split("")).map(x->(x.equals(x.toUpperCase())&&!x.equals(" "))?"":x).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use StringBuffer instead of String.
2. Use
   `i < l`
   Or
   `i <= l-1`
   Because the indexing starts with 0 and the the last element has index l-1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is forgotten minus l when you remove this character :D

Comment: Ummm im sorry but could you explain? Thanks anyways

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I just mention about the logic, You check the `Character.isUpperCase(ch) == true`. If it's true, you remove this character. At this time, the length of the string is decrease 1. So if you don't decrease `l`, the error will be shown.